# Duplicate entry Magento Super Link

Tags: mysql, magento, magento-1.9

When I try to save an associated product shows the error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '3044-2812' for key 'UNQ_CATALOG_PRODUCT_SUPER_LINK_PRODUCT_ID_PARENT_ID', query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_super_link` (`product_id`,`parent_id`) VALUES (?, ?)

Already cleared the cache and reindex, but it not work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to format the blockquote so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit in to provide additional detail that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Comment: please see https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/160354/magento-1-truncate-catalog-product-super-link/296004#296004 It is the same issue, but wrongly titled